# Vue.js dropdown issue in IE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer

I have created a form using Vue.js where the user can save their answers and come back. I have a dropdown in my Vue template and the v-model is tied to a computed property. It works fine in other browsers but in IE the dropdown is not showing the previously selected answer as selected when the page loads. It works fine if they answer again but I want their previously selected answer to be shown.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="answerLocal" @change="updatedAnswer()">
       <option v-for="option in possibleanswers">
             {{option}}
       </option>
</select>

 computed: {
        answerLocal: {
            get: function () {
                if (this.responses && this.responses.length) {
                    return this.responses[0].value;
                }

                return '';
            },
            set: function (val) {
                if (this.responses.length === 0) {
                    this.responses[0] = { value: '' };
                }
                this.responses[0].value = val;
            }
        }
```

possibleanswers is a property of the component and answerLocal is a computed property. responses is a property of the component and holds an array of objects.

Comment: can you share how you are storing/retrieving `answerLocal`?

Comment: @depperm, I added some more of the code. If anything else would be helpful, I can show more.

Comment: where does response come from?

Comment: @depperm Thanks for your help. response is passed as a property to the component. I use an Ajax call to get it from the backend to send to the component. I actually just figured out the answer though. I will post it below too but added v-bind:value="option" to the option tag in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the solution. I needed to add v-bind:value="option" to the option tag in the html. Updated html below.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="answerLocal" @change="updatedAnswer()">
       <option v-for="option in possibleanswers" v-bind:value="option">
             {{option}}
       </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.